# How to allow access to ECR repo from multiple companies AWS Accounts to pull from private ECR repo of one company

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am unsure if this is possible but I have a request to setup a ECR repository that I would like to setup in my company AWS Account and manage to publish the images and helm chart by myself.

But I have partners who also need to pull images and helm chart from this ECR repo, How can I achieve this, Any IAM Insight would help too.

Comment: Is this what you need? https://serverfault.com/questions/897392/ecr-cross-account-pull-permissions

Comment: But is this possible in a private ECR repo ? I think my ask is for how to allow 2 other company AWS Accounts to allow access to this ECR for pull only.

Comment: Yes, works for private ECR repos.